# Dropdown not being populated from HTTP response

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to making HTTP calls.  I am trying to populate (specific) properties of each object into the dropdown but it is not being populated, I tried a couple of things i.e for loop

```
created(){
  axios
    .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
  .then(res => {
    let result = res.data
    for(i = 0; i <= result.length;i++){
      this.todos = result[i];
    }
  })
}
```

Meanwhile I also tried to log out one single value in the response in `<li>` which display fine.

```
  <ul>
    {{user.todos}}
  </ul>
```

but when I try to use `v-for` in select of the dropdown, it doesn't e.g

```
  <select name="" id="">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please Select..</option>
    <option value="" v-for="todo in user.todos">{{todo}}</option>
  </select>
```

Here is my full [codepen](https://codepen.io/codearts/pen/MLRwNw). What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can make it work:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    user: {
      todos: []
    }
  },
  created(){
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then(res => {
        cosnt result = res.data

        for(i = 0; i <= result.length;i++){
          this.user.todos.push(result[i].title);
        }
      })
  }
})
```

`this.user.todos` should be an array, if you assign a single value to it you won't be able to loop it to populate the select options.

Comment: great. thanks! Time to polish my JS skills. One another thing, is data a generic word?

Comment: @Nofel, you mean `data` in the Vue component or the `data` from the response.

Comment: sorry shld have clarified. ```data``` from the response

Comment: That depends entirely from the API that you use, it could be called anything.